WP_Term_Query offset argument
I am trying to return product categories but with an offset, however it doesn't matter what I put in the offset it always returns all of them. This is my $args array:
array(6) {
  ["taxonomy"]=>
  string(11) "product_cat"
  ["order"]=>
  string(3) "ASC"
  ["orderby"]=>
  string(6) "parent"
  ["hide_empty"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["parent"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["offset"]=>
  int(3)
}

I've tried as a string value too. Any idea where I'm going wrong?
Thanks
Rich

When using offset you also need to use the number argument to include how many terms you wish to return as well, otherwise it doesn't work!
